# Swift 3 Contextual type 'AnyObject' Cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I was porting from swift2.3 to swift3 and ran into the following problem.

I am trying to return a dictionary of value dictionary in the function below. But is getting the error `Contextual type 'AnyObject' Cannot be used with dictionary literal`

I have tried manually bridging the value as `AnyObject` after looking for some answers but to no avail.

`typealias Payload = [String: AnyObject]`

```
func toCreatePayload() -> Payload {
    let payload: [String: [String:AnyObject]] =
        ["saving_rule": ["description": title as AnyObject,
                         "amount": amount! as AnyObject,
                         "background_color": (backgroundColor?.toHexString())! as AnyObject,
                         "saving_rule_category_id": category!.remoteId as AnyObject,
                         "saving_rule_sub_category_id": subCategory != nil ? subCategory!.remoteId : ("" as AnyObject),
                         "saving_rule_condition_id": condition != nil ? condition!.remoteId : ("" as AnyObject),
                         "saving_rule_condition_customizations_attributes": customizations.map({$0.toCreatePayload()}) as AnyObject,
                         "suspended": "false"] as AnyObject
        ]
    return payload as [String:AnyObject]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` :

```
func toCreatePayload() -> Payload {
    let payload: [String: [String:Any]] =
        ["saving_rule": ["description": title,
                         "amount": amount!,
                         "background_color": (backgroundColor?.toHexString())!,
                         "saving_rule_category_id": category!.remoteId,
                         "saving_rule_sub_category_id": subCategory != nil ? subCategory!.remoteId : "",
                         "saving_rule_condition_id": condition != nil ? condition!.remoteId : "",
                         "saving_rule_condition_customizations_attributes": customizations.map({$0.toCreatePayload()}),
                         "suspended": "false"]
        ]
    return payload
}
```

The difference:

- **Any** can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types and optional types.
- **AnyObject** can represent an instance of any class type.

Comment: We would need to cast the return type as such, `return payload as [String: AnyObject]`.

Comment: @MaTaKazer A type cast is not needed, change the typealias to `[String:Any]`, too

Comment: Is there any side effect with changing it from `AnyObject` to `Any`? I am getting confused with this.